# How do I call javascript from asp.net button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm working on asp.net and want to execute following javascript code.
I'm using VS2010.

```
   <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myClosure() {
        var canyousee = "here I'm ";
        return (function theClosure() {
            return { canyouseeIt: canyousee ? "yes" : "no" };
        });
    }
    var closure = myClosure();
    closure().canyouseeIt;
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="myClosure();" />
    </div>
```

How do i execute `function myClosure()` on button click so that It gives me `confirm` i.e popup for `yes` or `no` ?

1. Which code I need to put for `confirm` ?
2. How can I execute it on `Button Click` ?

thanks

Comment: that's not alert, that's confirm

Comment: which code should I need to add for that ?

Comment: confirm('this is a yes no question') and it returns boolean value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this can be of some help. 
I must confess that what you want to achieve is not clear to me.

```
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
     myClosure=function() {
        var canyousee = "here I'm ";
        return (function () {
            return { canyouseeIt: function(){return confirm (canyousee)}};
        });
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="(myClosure())().canyouseeIt()" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myClosure(){
          var r=confirm("Press a button!")
        if (r==true)
        {
             alert("You pressed OK!")
             return true;
        }
        else
        {
              alert("You pressed Cancel!");
              return false;
        }

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="myClosure();" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

use

```
onclientclick="javascript:return YourFunction();"

<script> 
function YourFunction() {
//Do your stuff

return true;
}
</script>
```

If you return true your asp.new onclick event will be called..
If you return false it wont be called..

Answer (score 1):

as you call it, but prevent the post back by return false on

```
OnClientClick="myClosure();return false;"
```

I do not know nether understand the rest of your logic, but this is your issue right now.

Comment: not working for me :( in my logic i'm basically tried to work on `javascript closure` concept nothing else.

Comment: @ashuthinks When I say, your logic, I mean your steps you like to follow. Anyway, check for other javascript errors. This is the way